# The problem of running the program in Android Studio

Tags: android

I don't know why I face this problem when creating a new program. I tried to find the problem, but no matter how much I searched, I couldn't find the result. This was not a problem in the implementation of the first program . I will be glad to help.
here error : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC13L.png)

Comment: Check your dependencies, try invalidating cache, cleaning build!

Comment: Have you actually added `appcompat` as a dependency? See here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#declaring_dependencies

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.